# Lubuntu 18.04 won't start without nomodeset

Tags: lubuntu, intel

I know there are many threads on this, but I've tried seemingly everything and nothing has worked so far. Running Lubuntu 18.04 on a Dell Inspiron 11-3162.

`lspci | grep VGA` gives me:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 21)
```

Lubuntu 18.04 will always go to a black screen after GRUB without 'nomodeset'.

I would just run it with `nomodeset`, but I want to change the brightness and it seems like I can't do that unless I get the graphics card being used.

I've tried reinstalling drivers etc, but nothing seems to work.

Any and all tips are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include information about the graphics card in your system.